# How to get Flutter TextField onLongpress callback when textfield has focus?

Tags: flutter, textfield, long-press

Is it a way to get the onLongpress call from flutter TextField? It has an onTap callback by defaul, but i need the onLongpress ?

```
TextField(onLongpress : ()=>...
```

Detailed behaviour :

1. text field is focused,cursor is blinking
2. Longpress on textfield
3. Override textfield on lonpress behaviour
   (By default textfield selects a word under the cursor)

Comment: surround it with a gesturedetector widget, that has a longpress callback

Answer (score 5):

I could have given you a more direct approach if I know your Use Case.

But this works Pretty Fine.

```
   InkWell(
       onLongPress: () {
                print("onlong Press");
                },
              child: IgnorePointer(
                ignoring: true,  // You can make this a variable in other toggle True or False 
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    hintText: 'Enter Password',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: the problem is, that when you inside the TextField , so to speak in 'edit mode' , other gesture detectors wont be fire callbacks, only TextField own gesture detectors would work.

Comment: pls, make your comment clearer and well detailed As much as you can. I would really love to help.